# Fixing list output in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dutch-national-flag-problem

I'm trying to make a solver for the Dutch National flag problem. Basically, given a list, I want to sort them in the order of Red-White-Blue. Red, White and Blue are defined by their predicates (i.e. red(x), white(x) etc.)
Currently, I have the following code:

```
red(1).
white(2).
blue(3).

dutch(Xs,Ys):- 
    getRed(Xs,[], Red), getWhite(Xs,[],White), getBlue(Xs,[],Blue), 
    append([], Red, Y1), append(Y1, White, Y2), append(Y2, Blue, Ys).

getRed([],Rs,Rs).
getRed([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- red(X), getRed(Rest, [X,Acc] , Rs).
getRed([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- getRed(Rest, Acc, Rs).

getWhite([],Rs,Rs).    
getWhite([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- white(X), getWhite(Rest, [X,Acc], Rs).
getWhite([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- getWhite(Rest, Acc, Rs).

getBlue([],Rs,Rs).
getBlue([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- blue(X), getBlue(Rest, [X,Acc], Rs).    
getBlue([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- getBlue(Rest, Acc, Rs).
```

My output looks like this :

```
?- dutch([1,2,3],R).
R = [1, [], 2, [], 3, []]
R = [1, [], 2, []]
R = [1, [], 3, []]
R = [1, []]
R = [2, [], 3, []]
R = [3, []]
R = []
```

What I want is for it to look like this:

```
R = [1, 2, 3]
```

I've tried a few ways to force the output to what i want, but haven't been able to get anywhere close.

Edit: Looks like i can solve it by using a brute force solution of permuting all possible sets and evaluating whether the set is in "Dutch Flag" order. Is there a better solution though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two errors in your code:

1) your terminal clauses `getRed([],Rs,Rs)`, `getWhite([],Rs,Rs)`, `getBlue([],Rs,Rs)` accepting, as value result, the empty list (when `Rs` is equal to `[]`); I suggest to rewrite they as

```
getRed([],Rs,Rs)   :- Rs \= [].
getWhite([],Rs,Rs) :- Rs \= [].
getBlue([],Rs,Rs)  :- Rs \= [].
```

2) in the accepting clause (when `X` is the searched color), you add it in the accumulator with a comma when you should use a pipe (`[X,Acc]`; should be (`[X|Acc]`); I suggest to rewrite they as

```
getRed([X|Rest], Acc, Rs)   :- red(X),   getRed(Rest, [X|Acc], Rs).
getWhite([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- white(X), getWhite(Rest, [X|Acc] , Rs).
getBlue([X|Rest], Acc, Rs)  :- blue(X),  getBlue(Rest, [X|Acc], Rs).
```

Off Topic: There is no reason to append `Red` to an empty list; the result list (`Y1`) is `Red` itself; I suggest to semplify

```
append([], Red, Y1), append(Y1, White, Y2), append(Y2, Blue, Ys)
```

as follows

```
append(Red, White, Mid), append(Mid, Blue, Ys)
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Not sure about what do you exactly want but I suspect a third error in the third version clauses: when `X` isn't accumulated.

I think you should add a check to be sure that `X` isn't the searched color; I suggest to rewrite they as follows

```
getRed([X|Rest], Acc, Rs)   :- \+ red(X),   getRed(Rest, Acc, Rs).
getWhite([X|Rest], Acc, Rs) :- \+ white(X), getWhite(Rest, Acc, Rs).
getBlue([X|Rest], Acc, Rs)  :- \+ blue(X),  getBlue(Rest, Acc, Rs).
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

I don't see the need of an accumulator in your `getRed/3`, `getWhite/3` and `getBlue/3` clauses.

I propose a version with only 2 arguments

```
red(1).
white(2).
blue(3).

dutch(Xs,Ys):- 
    getRed(Xs, Red), getWhite(Xs, White), getBlue(Xs, Blue), 
    append(Red, White, Mid), append(Mid, Blue, Ys).

getRed([],[]).
getRed([X|Rest], [X|Rs]) :- red(X),    getRed(Rest, Rs).
getRed([X|Rest], Rs)     :- \+ red(X), getRed(Rest, Rs).

getWhite([],[]).
getWhite([X|Rest], [X|Rs]) :- white(X),    getWhite(Rest, Rs).
getWhite([X|Rest], Rs)     :- \+ white(X), getWhite(Rest, Rs).

getBlue([],[]).
getBlue([X|Rest], [X|Rs]) :- blue(X),    getBlue(Rest, Rs).
getBlue([X|Rest], Rs)     :- \+ blue(X), getBlue(Rest, Rs).
```

Comment: Thank you for the prolog tips! I'm pretty new to prolog and don't know much about the programming practices. For the most part, i was simply trying to get my code running and was hastily making changes to test out different implementations. I will keep those in mind for any future code that i right.

Comment: @Terence - you're wellcome; added another suggestion

Answer (score 1):

## A pure solution

### Preface

I would like to add a **pure**, **relational** solution to the existing one.

Ideally, you can use a Prolog predicate in **all directions**, and I will now show an implementation that lets you do this: Not only can you sort an *instantiated* list according to your criteria, no, you can also **generate** solutions and **complete** partially instantiated solutions.

To do this, I am using the meta-predicate **`if_/3`** from [**`library(reif)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl).

### Reified predicates

I start with the *reified* versions of your predicates, also taking the liberty to use the more telling names `red`, `white` and `blue` to denote the colors:

```
red(R, T)   :- =(R, red, T).

white(W, T) :- =(W, white, T).

blue(B, T)  :- =(B, blue, T).
```

Note I am using `(=)/3`, which ships for free with `library(reif)`.

### Using DCGs to describe lists

Next, purely for convenience, I am using **[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** notation to describe the subsequences of interest:

```
reds([]) --> [].
reds(Rs) -->
        [R],
        { if_(red(R), Rs = [R|Rest], Rs = Rest) },
        reds(Rest).

whites([]) --> [].
whites(Ws) --> [W],
        { if_(white(W), Ws = [W|Rest], Ws = Rest) },
        whites(Rest).

blues([]) --> [].
blues(Bs) --> [B],
        { if_(blue(B), Bs = [B|Rest], Bs = Rest) },
        blues(Rest).
```

I leave making this more concise as an easy exercise.

### Solution

With these building blocks, we can express the overall solution:

```
dutch(Colors, Ds) :-
        phrase(reds(Rs), Colors),
        phrase(whites(Ws), Colors),
        phrase(blues(Bs), Colors),
        phrase((Rs,Ws,Bs), Ds).
```

### Examples

Of course, this works in simple, *instantiated* cases like:

```
?- dutch([red,white,blue], Ds).
Ds = [red, white, blue] ;
false.
```

Now the point: This **also** works in the **most general case**, where all arguments are *variables*:

```
?- length(Cs, _), dutch(Cs, Ds).
Cs = Ds, Ds = [] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [white] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [blue] ;
Cs = [_G1322],
Ds = [],
dif(_G1322, blue),
dif(_G1322, white),
dif(_G1322, red) ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, red] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, white] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, blue] ;
Cs = [red, _G1340],
Ds = [red],
dif(_G1340, blue),
dif(_G1340, white),
dif(_G1340, red) .
```

By adding further goals, we can *specialize* this query to observe concrete **solutions** that are now generated:

```
?- length(Cs, _), Cs = [_,_,_|_], dutch(Cs, Ds), ground(Cs).
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, red, red] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, red, white] ;
Cs = Ds, Ds = [red, red, blue] ;
Cs = [red, white, red],
Ds = [red, red, white] ;
Cs = [red, blue, red],
Ds = [red, red, blue] .
```

Compare this with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40241423/772868), which *cannot* be used to fairly enumerate solutions:

```
?- length(Xs, _), Xs = [_,_,_|_], dutch(Xs, Ys).
Xs = Ys, Ys = [1, 1, 1] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] .
```

### Summary

Thus, by retaining [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) we have obtained a **more general** logic program, which we can use in all directions.

Admittedly, you did not request this generality. However, while we are at it, *why waive it*?